# Google Maps API : what UI metaphors are available to signify a user's choosing a location on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have been tasked to write an application that gives the users these capabilites:

1. Open a map centered on the USA [this I know how to do]
2. User can either double-click  multiple times or use the zoom control or pan the map 
   any number of times, to their hearts' content
3. User ultimately "chooses" a region (e.g. Finger Lakes District of NY) or a town or metropolitan area (e.g. Walla Walla, Washington or Detroit).
4. I have to get the latitude and longitude of the user's chosen location.

I've found in the API docs how to open a map centered on a lat/lon and how to include the zoom controls. But what UI action could the user take to signal "this is the place I choose"? The user has already been clicking to zoom the map, so a simple click won't suffice to signal the user has made her choice. Should the user drop the little orange man onto the map? Does that raise an event I can listen for, which will give me the orange man's position?  Are there other UI metaphors available that could be used for this purpose?

P.S. The user may or may not be clicking. The zoom control and panning could be used instead. So I cannot rely upon the click event.  What is needed is a UI gesture or metaphor that means *explicitly*  "this is the area I choose".

Comment: You may find some good ideas if you ask over on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I have never visited there. Will do.

Answer (score 1):

This code, for example, would show the LatLng, the user has clicked on

```
display.getGoogleMap().addClickHandler(new ClickMapHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(ClickMapEvent event) {
        MouseEvent me = event.getMouseEvent();
        LatLng ll = me.getLatLng();
        Window.alert("clicked: "+ ll.getToString());
    }
});
```

Why don´t you use an extra, unobtrusively Panel or Overlay, in which the chosen LatLng (or Region) is displayed: "Actual region: ..." and a small button under this info: "save".

Your possibility, in which you drag something, is also possible.

Comment: The suggestion to use a button which would save the most recent location place the user has clicked on would work, if the user remembers to click. My users might be using the zoom control and panning until they see before them the region they're interested in. Does the API return the lat/lon on which the currently displayed region at the current zoom level is centered? BTW, this would be a web app HTML/javascript.

Comment: Should your app center to the position, the user has clicked on during zoom? If true, solution would be simple. The app could figure out, which LatLng was clicked and center on it. To identify your region then, you could take your value back with `map.getCenter();`

Comment: There's no guarantee that the user will have clicked on an area. They might simply have zoomed using the zoom control, and then panned. My users are not tech-savvy people, generally speaking. Some of them talk into the mouse... almost.

Comment: But if the user clicks... whereever... you could detect the LatLng, where he clicked, and center on this LatLng.

Comment: By that I meant that the user won't always be clicking.